# JavaScript Regex split at first letter?

Tags: javascript, regex

Since many cases using Regex, differs from case to case, depending on what format your string is in, I'm having a hard time finding a solution to my problem.

I have an array containing strings in the format, as an example:

`"XX:XX - XX:XX Algorithm and Data Structures"`

Where `"XX:XX - XX:XX"` is timespan for a lecture, and `X` being a number.

I'm new to Regex and trying to split the string at the first letter occurring, like so:

```js
let str = "08:15 - 12:50 Algorithm and Data Structures";
let re = //Some regex expression
let result = str.split(re); // Output: ["08:15 - 12:50", "Algorithm and Data Structures"]
```

I'm thinking it should be something like `/[a-Z]/` but I'm not sure at all...

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Does your string always have a fixed length in the part where you display the time?

Comment: Did any of the answers work out?

Comment: I've only tested dave and DemiPixel's answers, and they both worked great

Comment: Please consider accepting one so future visitors can easily identify the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to "mark" where you want to split and then split:

```
const str = '12 34 abcde 45 abcde'.replace(/^([^a-z]+)([a-z])/i, '$1,$2');
// '12 34 ,abcde 45 abcde'
str.split(',')
// [ '12 34 ', 'abcde 45 abcde' ]
```

This finds the place where the string starts, has a bunch of non a-z characters, then has an a-z characters, and puts a comma right in-between. Then you split by the comma.

You can also split directly with a positive look ahead but it might make the regex a bit less readable.

Comment: That seems like a really good way to handle the problem. Could you maybe explain what ```^([^a-z]+)``` and ```'$1,$2'``` does, so I might improve my understanding of Regex? :D

Comment: The parenthesis don't change anything, they just say "remember this group for later". `[^a-z]` means "any character in the world except a-z". The `+` means "one or more", so one or more non a-z characters. The `$1` means "the contents of group 1" and the `$2` means "the contents of group 2". Because we're doing a `replace`, all of the characters being matched are completely replaced, so if you remove those and just leave the comma, you'll notice that everything up to and including the first letter would be replaced with just a comma. https://regexr.com/ is good for helping explain regex too!

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! I will definitely look into it - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(
    "08:15 - 12:50 Algorithm and Data Structures".split(/ ([A-Za-z].*)/).filter(Boolean)
)
```

or, if it's really always `XX:XX - XX:XX`, easier to just do:

```js
const splitTimeAndCourse = (input) => {
    return [
        input.slice(0, "XX:XX - XX:XX".length),
        input.slice("XX:XX - XX:XX".length + 1)
    ]
    
}

console.log(splitTimeAndCourse("08:15 - 12:50 Algorithm and Data Structures"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed length of the string where the time is, you can use this regex for example

```
(^.{0,13})(.*)
```

Check this here https://regex101.com/r/ANMHy5/1

Answer (score 0):

For that format, you might also use 2 capture groups instead of using split.

```
^(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*-\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})\s+([A-Za-z].*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*-\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})` Capture group 1, match a timespan like pattern
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitspac chars
- `([A-Za-z].*)` Capture group 2, start with a char A-Za-z and match the rest of the line.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mngkd7/1)

```js
let str = "08:15 - 12:50 Algorithm and Data Structures";
let regex = /^(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*-\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})\s+([A-Za-z].*)/;
let [, ...groups] = str.match(regex);
console.log(groups);
```

Another option using split might be asserting not any chars a-zA-Z to the left from the start of the string using a lookbehind *(see [this link](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) for the support)*, match 1+ whitespace chars and asserting a char a-zA-Z to the right.

```
(?<=^[^a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?=[A-Za-z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zKFHRj/1)

```js
let str = "08:15 - 12:50 Algorithm and Data Structures";
let regex = /(?<=^[^a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?=[A-Za-z])/;
console.log(str.split(regex))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about regex in particular, but here is a way to this without regex...

Provided your ***time span*** is always at the *beginning* of your string and will always be *formatted* with white space between the numbers as `XX:XX - XX:XX`. You could use a function that splits the string at the white space and reconstructs the first three indexed strings into one chunk, ***the time span***, and the last remaining strings into a second chunk, ***the lecture title***. Then return the two chunks as an array.

```js
let str = "08:15 - 12:50 Algorithm and Data Structures";

const splitString = (str) => {
  // split the string at the white spaces
  const strings = str.split(' ')
  // define variables
  let lecture = '',
    timespan = '';
  // loop over the strings
  strings.forEach((str, i) => {
    // structure the timespan
    timespan = `${strings[0]} ${strings[1]} ${strings[2]}`;
    // conditional to get the remaining strings and concatenate them into a new string
    i > 2 && i < strings.length?lecture += `${str} `: '';
  })
  // place them into an array and remove white space from end of second string
  return [timespan, lecture.trimEnd()]
}


console.log(splitString(str))
```